# intellij idea gradle plugin unable to use relative paths specified in gradle.properties

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a Gradle project perfectly running (from the command line), configured to use a JDK specified with a relative path.

For this, I added a `gradle.properties` file to my project, containing:

```
org.gradle.java.home = jdk/
```

But when I try to run the build from Intellij Idea (14.0.3), I get:

```
Java home supplied via 'org.gradle.java.home' is invalid. Invalid directory: jdk/
```

Using absolute paths solves the issue. Do I misuse the gradle.properties or I just have to report a bug to Jetbrains, related to their Gradle plugin?

Comment: Gradle and Idea are likely resolving the relative path differently. In general, Gradle resolves paths relative to the project directory (that is, the directory with the build.gradle file).

Comment: Thanks for answer! I will try to reach someone from Jetbrains.

Comment: It seems this is still a problem on 2020.1.2

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with IntelliJ's Gradle plugin, which you can upvote in their issue tracker here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-208432