# Specify a relative path in gradle.properties

Tags: java, gradle

I need java 8 for a gradle project of mine and want to enable others to use it "out of the box" without changing their environment. So I want to add a specific jdk to version control and make gradle (and gradle wrapper) use it.

I found this:
[How do I tell Gradle to use specific JDK version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487406/how-do-i-tell-gradle-to-use-specific-jdk-version)
but it doesn't say how to specify a relative path.

In gradle.properties I have:

```
org.gradle.java.home = <path to jdk>
```

how can I use it with a relative path?
It's in the parent directory, so it would be something like:

```
org.gradle.java.home = ../resources/jdk8
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the gradle wrapper, you could edit the batch/shell file to specify the JAVA_HOME as a local path.

Comment: Great, thanks, that worked, a solution that would also work for the regular gradle would be neat but this is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit `org.gradle.java.home` of file `gradle.properties` to point to a relative location. For example, suppose your JVM is in directory `java/jdk` inside your Gradle project root, you can edit the file with:

`org.gradle.java.home=./java/jdk`

Comment: Note that this fails if you try to run Gradle from inside IntelliJ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28726011/intellij-idea-gradle-plugin-unable-to-use-relative-paths-specified-in-gradle-pro